# Please check the mnemonic rhyme for adjectives

Tags: adjectives, word-order, adjective-order, mnemonic

According to the English grammar, the adjectives between article and noun should be in order:

1. opinion
2. size
3. shape
4. condition
5. age
6. color
7. pattern
8. origin
9. material
10. purpose

In order to remember this, I build an English mnemonic rhyme by myself:

> a lovely small thin sex-hungry 21-year-old girl'red striped Japanese silk sleeping underwear.

Don't laugh at me, I just want to memorize it well. Is it okay?
If possible, would you give me a good example which includes all the adjectives and is more easily to remember?

Comment: I have never heard of this alleged rule of English grammar.  It might be correct... but it is not consciously taught in American schools.

Comment: In recent generations, English authors have tried to avoid the "purple prose" that his alleged rule covers.  I looked at samples from a few books to verify this alleged rule.  Two of them (J.R.R. Tolkien's *The Return of the King* -- originally published in 1955 -- and Jerry Pournelle's *Janissaries* -- from 1979) did not seem to have pairs of adjectives.  Lois McMaster Bujold's *Diplomatic Immunity* -- from 2002 -- had a few examples.  Laura Ingalls Wilder's *Little House on the Prairie* -- from 1935, describing the early 1870s -- had many examples....

Comment: ... My impression was that between 50% and 80% of the examples were consistent with this alleged rule.  So this alleged rule might help you in writing things, but do not rely on it to interpret things.  *Little House on the Prairie* is widely read to American children.  It is written in a very simple style, using ordinary words.  It epitomizes "plain English" and "English that sounds natural to an American ear".

Comment: Funny enough, this has just been a topic a few days ago in cambridge's dictionaryblog: [A nice, relaxing bath (Adjective order)](http://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/12/03/a-nice-relaxing-bath-adjective-order/). Maybe that article may help you, too.

Comment: Even if this rule is sort of true, I recommend that you _not_ memorize it. Memorized rules help you get started. You should pick up the language mainly through experience listening, talking, reading, and writing. Then you'll know _the language_ rather than a list of memorized rules. Also, this is not a rule of English grammar like "the verb must agree in number with its subject". It's just a pattern that adjectives often follow but sometimes don't.

Comment: I don't find it a suitable mnuemonic at all. For one, I find it juvenile, tasteless, sexist and vulgar. (Would _you_ want to use this when teaching your 14-year-old daughter an English lesson? I wouldn't.)  Also, I think you've chosen some poor examples for a few of these categories of adjectives. For example, _age_ is not necessarily a numeric age; a word like _old_ or _new_ would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your mnemonic seems good for its purpose.

You should know that the rule in question does have exceptions, and this is actually a shockingly complicated and controversial subject:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order

As Jasper noted, most native English speakers are not taught this rule but instead absorb what sounds natural through osmosis.  While the rule might be helpful for writing, I don't think you'll ever be able to apply it at conversation speed, and you should probably supplement it with repetitive practice of common multi-adjective phrases.